# Howto get the correct CSS item for DatePicker (JavaFX 8)

Tags: css, javafx, datepicker

[image]

Hi guys, do you know howto edit the TextField border-color and border-width (currently a thin red border) within the **DatePicker** control? ? BTW where can I find good reference to available CSS items of JavaFX controls?

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your CSS file change this properties (from modena.css):

```
.date-picker > .text-field {
    -fx-background-color:
        linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-text-box-border, -10%), -fx-text-box-border),
        linear-gradient(from 0px 0px to 0px 5px, derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -9%), -fx-control-inner-background);
    -fx-background-insets: 1 0 1 1;
    -fx-background-radius: 2 0 0 2;
}

.date-picker:focused > .text-field,
.date-picker > .text-field:focused {
    -fx-background-color:
        -fx-control-inner-background,
        -fx-faint-focus-color,
        linear-gradient(from 0px 0px to 0px 5px, derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -9%), -fx-control-inner-background);
    -fx-background-insets: 1 0 1 1, 1 0 1 1, 3 2 3 3;
    -fx-background-radius: 2 0 0 2, 1 0 0 1, 0;
}
```

Good reference: [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I am looking for! Thanks a lot!

Comment: is there a way to style datepicker's button?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking, I've found [this](https://dx.dragan.ba/javafx-datepicker-custom-css/) javafx css example for designing DatePickers:

```
.date-picker .arrow-button {
-fx-background-color: -fx-primary-color;
-fx-background-radius: 0;
}
.date-picker .arrow-button:hover {
-fx-background-color: -fx-secondary-color;
}
.date-picker .arrow-button .arrow {
-fx-background-color: white;
}
.date-picker .cell {
-fx-background-color: white;
}
.date-picker .cell:hover {
-fx-background-color: -fx-light-grey-color;
}
.date-picker .cell:focused {
-fx-background-color: -fx-light-grey-color;
}
.date-picker .selected {
-fx-background-color: -fx-primary-color;
-fx-text-fill: white;
}
.date-picker .selected:focused {
-fx-background-color: -fx-primary-color;
-fx-text-fill: white;
}
.date-picker-popup  {
-fx-border-color: transparent;
}
.date-picker-popup .month-year-pane {
-fx-background-color: -fx-primary-color;
}
.date-picker-popup .month-year-pane .label {
-fx-text-fill: white;
}
.date-picker-popup .week-number-cell {
-fx-text-fill: -fx-secondary-color;
}
.date-picker-popup .spinner .button .left-arrow,
.date-picker-popup .spinner .button .right-arrow {
-fx-background-color: white;
}
```